# Disable/enable anchor tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to enable an anchor element using JavaScript but it looks like I am having some syntax issues. The disable part works fine but the anchor is not getting enabled after a time interval.

Form:

```
<a id="downloadReportLink"
   href="#x"
   title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions."
   onclick="document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit(), doEverything(this)">

   <span>Export E-Sign Information</span>
</a>
```

JS functions:

```
function disableLink(link) {
    link.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

function enableLink(link) {
    link.onclick = undefined;
}

function doEverything(link) {
    disableLink(link);
    setTimeout(function() {
            enableLink(link);
        },
        4000
    );
}
```

I assumed `link.onclick = undefined` would enable the anchor but it does not.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You are first submitted a form, as soon as the browser Submits a form, no other javascript will be executed.

Comment: Shouldn't the comma be a semicolon?

`document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit(), doEverything(this)`

Comment: I believe your code "works" in that during the four-second interval, clicking the link will not navigate to `#x`, and after that interval, it will. But is that actually what you wanted to do? What do you want clicking the link to do before, during, and after those four seconds?

Comment: First I submit the form then after the first click the link disables and after 4 secs i want it to be enabled.

Comment: @Jaykumar But what does "enabled" here mean? Do you want it to submit the form again after it's "enabled?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what behavior you **want**, but assuming you want to restore the original `onclick` of the anchor tag after the four-second interval, I think this will work for you. You were setting `link.onclick` to `undefined`, but you really want to set it back to what it was before.

(I'm also assuming that you're intercepting the form submit and not actually navigating away from the page.)

```js
function disableLink(link) {
    link.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

function enableLink(link, onclick) {
    link.onclick = onclick;
}

function doEverything(link) {
    var oldOnclick = link.onclick;
    disableLink(link);
    setTimeout(function() {
        enableLink(link, oldOnclick);
    }, 4000);
}
```

```html
<a id="downloadReportLink"
   href="#x"
   title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions."
   onclick="console.log('SUBMITTING'); doEverything(this); return false;">

   <span>Export E-Sign Information</span>
</a>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. This is awesome. Thank you so much smarx for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function disableLink(link) {
link.addEventListener("click", function(){
return false;
});

 }

function enableLink(link) {
link.addEventListener("click", function(){
return true;
});
```